# How to use a single backgroundthread method that called again and again

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading

I have a model class the fetches the database information, for this I have `getInfo()` method in my database class. In my main class I have table view to display the data in table view I want to call this database class method gain and again , If data is no there in the database I am firing a request on the server from the same method of database. To prevent view blocking I am calling `performselectorInBackgroundThread()`. Things are doing fine, but my question is that that, I am not a different background thread for every request. Is it good?. I want to create a single backgoundthread method to which I can use again and again. Please guid me with some code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD of course!

Create an serial dispatch queue

```
dispatch_queue_t _queue ;
_queue = dispatch_queue_create("Queue.database", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

when you want to do database work, do it like this, an example for query.

```
- (void)asyncQueryUserId:(NSString *)userId completeBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *))block
{
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        // data base work
        NSArray * users = queryDB(userId) ;
        // after do the work and get the result
        // you may want the result to continue your logic
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            block(users) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;
}
```

More about [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)